# How can I duplicate (clone) a tab in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea

In Eclipse I just click above the tab and click on "New Editor". In NetBeans is "Clone". In IntelliJ Idea I didn't find this option yet. What I do now is split vertically but it is not what I want.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't have multiple tabs for the same file without using split
mode (vertical or horizontal). If you want a copy of the file, use
Refactor | Copy.

To quickly split the view and make the same file visible in 2 splits hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and drag the tab into the editor area.

**UPDATE**: feature request added, [please vote](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91238).

Comment: This answer was provided by the official IntelliJ IDEA support.

Comment: I have no permissions to view this issue =(

Comment: @Mir-Ismaili the link should work now, sorry for the problem.

Comment: Seems that this feature is added as said in [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41759976/1317018). Is it so?

Comment: Time to edit this answer. You can now CTRL + mouse drag the file tab to duplicate it.

Comment: Use Cmd for mac.

Comment: You can also right click an already open tab in the editor and select `Split Down` or `Split Right` to get the same behavior.

Answer (score 19):

1. Split Vertically
2. Drag second tab to another Window/Monitor

Comment: You can also do this by holding CTRL and dragging the tab to a new monitor (or any space outside the main window). It'll automatically duplicate the tab in a new window and leave the old tab in the same window. Also works for cloning tabs between two or more windows.

Comment: So the feature is indeed added? I just checked. Dragged a tab in main window by pressing Ctrl to another (second) monitor. It opened another floating window with single tab showing that file, while the file in original tab still remains where it was. Also changing content in one tab also gets reflected in other tab.

Answer (score 16):

Use Shift + F4.

Ctrl + F4 to close it.

Comment: Best answer, as for me.

Answer (score 14):

You can do this simply by Holding CTRL button and drag the tab to the empty space or another monitor.

Comment: this should be the correct answer, it's also in a comment above

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 7):

You can drag the tab "out" of IntelliJ to create a new window with open tabs. Then reopen the file in main window.
See [this video](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/11/intellij-idea-10-eap-98311/)

This requires the new IntelliJ IDEA 10.

Comment: When I try to re-open the file in main window, it brings me back to 2ndary window.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, split (vertical or horizontal) is the only option that I have found.  You will find the IntelliJ support people really helpful, though, worth asking this question there:  http://www.jetbrains.com/support/idea/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Shift-Enter will open the file in a floating window.